# error when try to print two values

Tags: swift, printing

In the [official swift document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309) it says 
"*The `print(_:separator:terminator:)` function is a global function that prints one or **more** values to an appropriate output.*"

```
var welcomeMessage = "Hello"
var friendlyWelcom = "Hello!"

print(friendlyWelcom, separator: ",", terminator: "", welcomeMessage, separator: ",", terminator: "") // Why this is not working
```

**Question** As the comments inside the code - why do `print(friendlyWelcom, welcomeMessage)` and `print(friendlyWelcom, separator: ",", terminator: ""` work but `print(friendlyWelcom, separator: ",", terminator: "", welcomeMessage, separator: ",", terminator: "")` generates a compiler error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot simply add named parameters as you wish. Instead you should pass the variables to print in comma seperated as the first argument. They then get joined with the separator in between and the terminator at the end:

```
print(friendlyWelcom, welcomeMessage, separator: " - ", terminator: "?")
```

Outputs

> Hello! - Hello?

You can add as many variables there as you wish:

```
print(friendlyWelcom, welcomeMessage, 123, "somethingElse", "etc", separator: " - ", terminator: "!!!!")
```

> Hello! - Hello - 123 - somethingElse - etc!!!!

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, that's much clear for me now.